# Liberar fontes por domínio no .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|TTF)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(siteneme.com.br|www.sitename.com.br)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Tem algum modo de liberar as fontes em determinado dominio no .htaccess? Pois este modo que estou fazendo funciona só quando põe **www.sitename.com.br** porém se for no navegador e digitar **sitename.com.br**  da erro.

Comment: Qual erro que ocorre?

Comment: Font from origin 'http://www.sitename.com.br' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://sitename.com.br' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar lhe ajudar, é um pouco dificil, favoritei a pergunta para não perder ela, assim que conseguir posto aqui ;)

Comment: Obrigado :) to sem ideias ja kkk